# Wordpress throwing "The maximum number of databases you can create has been reached, so installation cannot proceed."

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hosting, cpanel

I am trying to install Wordpress on a hosted website. The domain allows one MySQL database.

However, when I try to do the install on the domain, I get the following error, "The maximum number of databases you can create has been reached, so installation cannot proceed."

Has anybody experienced this? How can I resolve it?

Comment: You should contact your host.

Comment: This is a hosting problem,but maybe you have a db you can drop?It goes without saying be careful.

Comment: That's not WordPress, that's a limitation set by your host. Have you already used up your one database?

Comment: (This question may close as it does not appear to be a programming question. The answer's above, anyway!).

Comment: I have this trouble, im contact my service provider and i was buy 5GB space now fix my problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks problem from hosting. Either delete any non-require database and create new or ask your server hosting provider for this.I think they will suggest you to buy more space for databases.